# What was the command of "Fire at will" before gunpowder?

Tags: etymology, verbs, history

I've seen some discussions about the command of "fire" before gunpowder was invented. That may be "shoot", "loose", "throw" etc. But what was the command of "fire at will"?  Are there any clues?

Update:
  "Fire at will" is a tactic which has long existed in history. After the invention of gunpowder, we call it "fire at will". Before gunpowder, what did we call this tactic? Was there a common used phrase or not?

Comment: I've always wondered who this poor guy Will is.  Apparently he's imprisoned now, since I often see people taking up an offering to free him.

Comment: @oerkelens I don't think it is duplicated. That question discussed about "Fire" but not "Fire at will".

Comment: For the story behind Fire At Will: http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/21/messages/999.html

Comment: I fail to see why _fire_ is so different fro  _fire at will_. The _at will_ part is independent from the existence of gunpowder. Would you really consider similar questions about _fire when you see the whites of their eyes_, _hold your fire_, _fire at my command_, etc as different questions? All of them share the point that _fire_ in a pre-gunpowder times was probably not used, but why would the rest of the sentence be gunpowder-dependent?

Comment: @oerkelens Phrases are time-dependent. Throwing a grenade and we shout "fire in hole!" but not "I've throwed a grenade!", because that is a phrase. Do you think it could be easily replaced the word "fire" with anything others like "shoot" then become "shoot at will"? Why it was not "shoot freely"? What I am asking is wether there existed such a commonly used phase in history equivalent to "fire at will".

Comment: @Hot Licks If you're brave enough to fire at will, yo'd better make sure your first shot is a telling one.

Comment: The verb _fire_ is "time-dependent", sure. What makes you think that _at will_ is (1) time dependent and (2) linked to gunpowder?

Comment: Isn't firing *in volleys* the opposite of firing *at will?* According to the OED, the word *volley* was not introduced until the late 16th century, when artillery and firearms were already in use.

Comment: @HotLicks Me too! Not sure who's worse off though, Will or Bill Posters ...

Comment: @oerkelens Do you have any refrence that they used "at will" after the verb but not other sayings? Yes, "at will" is not time-dependent, but it does not mean a verb followed with "at will" is a historical use.

Comment: [at will](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/at+will) in freedictionary, [cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/at-will) and [collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-will). Note the examples that Collins gives: _switch off at will_, _call up at will_, _come and go at will_. Absolutely nothing to suspect the _idiom_ **at will** has anything to do with gunpowder.

Comment: @oerkelens Why are you always trying to split a phrase into separate parts? What I mean of "historical use" is the historical use to describe such a tatic as "fire at will" before gunpowder time. I am not arguing if it is acceptable to say "shoot at will" in film or not. Was "shoot/loose/throw/... at will" really used as a commonly used command for that tatic in history?

Comment: Is you question about _fire_? Then it is a duplicate. Is your question about _at will_? Then it has nothing to do with gunpowder. Is your question about that random combination of _fire_ and _at will_, then I don't understand why that combination was chosen and maybe you should provide some more detail. _verb at will_ is a normal idiom, and if you are interested in the history of it, that might constitute a valid question. However, I do not see any relevance to gunpowder. If you _do_ see a link between the idiom _at will_ and _gunpowder_, please add that information to your question.

Comment: My question is about "fire at will", not "fire", not "at will", and not random combination, OK? "Fire at will" is a tatic which exists long in history. And after gunpowder time we call this tatic as "fire at will". My question is before gunpowder time what phrase we used to call this tatic or there was no common used phrase.

Comment: @Lord_WayneY: the tactic "fire at will" can be described quite easily with one sentence. How do you know that there was a short, fixed phrase for this concept before "fire at will" was introduced? Why would it have been needed? There aren't short fixed phrases for all currently used military tactics.

Comment: @PeterShor Actually I do not know if there are any. It maybe vary, maybe have a fixed one in a region. And that is just what the question asks...

Comment: So, flaming arrows couldn't be fire at will?  Attack when ready? "At will" is a long-known phrase.